# Error in DataBinding cannot find symbol class

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I use databinding  in my project and its working fine but today suddenly it give error `Error:(35, 13) error: cannot find symbol class AddPatientBinding`

here my gradle.build:-

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.octalsoftaware.archi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
/*            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true*/
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        /* debug {
             debuggable true
             minifyEnabled true
             shrinkResources true
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }*/
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true;
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    // Realm
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
    //network-related libraries
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.0'
    // swipe recyclerview
    compile 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    // This dude gave a shoutout to you (daimajia) on his github page:
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.0.3@aar'
    // Event Bus
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    // scale libraries
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    // fabric crash
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4-with-sources.jar')
    compile(project(':imagechoose'))
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here my logcat:-

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :imagechoose:generateDebugSources, :imagechoose:mockableAndroidJar, :imagechoose:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :imagechoose:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :imagechoose:compileDebugSources, :imagechoose:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :imagechoose:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\AddPatientActivity.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(35, 13) error: cannot find symbol class AddPatientBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\CancelCase.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(36, 13) error: cannot find symbol class CancelCaseBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\chargeinformation\CardiacAndTEE.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(36, 5) error: cannot find symbol class CardiacAndTeeBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\chargeinformation\ChangeInformation.java
Error:(21, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(58, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ChargeInformationBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\chargeinformation\InvasiveLinesActivity.java
Error:(15, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(38, 13) error: cannot find symbol class InvasiveLinesBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\chargeinformation\InvasiveLinesAndSpecialServices.java
Error:(15, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(35, 13) error: cannot find symbol class InvasiveLinesSpecialServicesBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\chargeinformation\PostOpPainBlocksOptions.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(32, 5) error: cannot find symbol class PostOpPainBlockOptionBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\chargeinformation\PostOpPlainBlocksActivity.java
Error:(15, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(38, 5) error: cannot find symbol class PostOpPainBlocksBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\chargeinformation\Procedures.java
Error:(13, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(29, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ProceduralBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\DiagnosisActivity.java
Error:(25, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(49, 5) error: cannot find symbol class DiagnosisActivityBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\HomeActivity.java
Error:(24, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(67, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HomePageBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\images\ImagesActivity.java
Error:(19, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(47, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ImagesBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\images\ImagesListActivity.java
Error:(18, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(43, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ImagesListBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\LocationActivity.java
Error:(25, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(49, 5) error: cannot find symbol class LocationSearchBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\LoginActivity.java
Error:(20, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(41, 13) error: cannot find symbol class LoginActivityBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\PatientDetailsActivity.java
Error:(16, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(42, 13) error: cannot find symbol class PatientDetailsBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\qualityinformation\AdvancedQIActivity.java
Error:(18, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(43, 13) error: cannot find symbol class AdvancedQaBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\qualityinformation\CardiovascularActivity.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(34, 5) error: cannot find symbol class QiCardiovascularBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\qualityinformation\ComplianceActivity.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(34, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ComplianceBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\qualityinformation\MorbidityMortality.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(34, 13) error: cannot find symbol class MorbidityMortalityBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\qualityinformation\NeurologicActivity.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(34, 13) error: cannot find symbol class NeurologicBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\qualityinformation\PharmacyBloodBank.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(34, 13) error: cannot find symbol class PharmacyBloodBankBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\qualityinformation\ProceduralActivity.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(34, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ProceduralBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\qualityinformation\QIAirwayRespiratoryActivity.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(34, 13) error: cannot find symbol class QiAirwayRespiratoryBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\qualityinformation\QualityInformation.java
Error:(17, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(39, 13) error: cannot find symbol class QualityInformationBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\views\activity\qualityinformation\RegionalActivity.java
Error:(14, 44) error: package com.octalsoftaware.archi.databinding does not exist
Error:(34, 13) error: cannot find symbol class RegionalBinding
E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\models\HomePageModal.java
Error:(12, 12) error: The fields of the model must be private
Warning:File for type 'io.realm.DefaultRealmModule' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
Warning:File for type 'io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 36.123 secs
Information:54 errors
Information:2 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I tries to rebuild and clean my project I also try Invalidate caches but all is vain. I use first time databinding  in my project anyone can help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any errors in your project because sometimes after implementing data binding, we need to manually find errors. So, go through the latest changes you might have done in your project.

Comment: No in my knowledge no error in my project. @SurajMakhija

Comment: Thanks @SurajMakhija you are right one error in my project I solve them and all error run away.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The key error is

> E:\Projects\Archi\Archi\app\src\main\java\com\octalsoftaware\archi\models\HomePageModal.java
>   Error:(12, 12) error: The fields of the model must be private

So when you set fields to private can solve this problem.